# Airflow: how to extend SubDagOperator?

Tags: airflow

When I try to extend the SubDagOperator provided in airflow API, airflow webserver GUI does not recognize it as SubDagOperator thereby disabling me to zoom in to the subdag.

How can I extend the SubDagOperator while preserving the ability to zoom in to it as a subdag? Am I missing something?

Comment: Whenever asking questions. It's always best to add an example of what you've tried so far. Helps people understand where the issue could be.

Comment: still no solutions? I read its code: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/9d5cc6ef5fe18055395ab671d602d70ab18dcbd2/airflow/models.py#L3450, this line indicates that airflow use the `SubDagOperator` to decide subdags. So I think it's not possible to extend the SubDagOperator, unless we change airflow code or waiting for the new versions to support this.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the example below on how to extend the SubDagOperator. The key in your case was to override the task_type function

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


class ExampleSubdagSubclassOperator(SubDagOperator):
  template_fields = ()
  template_ext = ()

  @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    dag = kwargs.get('dag')
    task_id = kwargs.get('task_id')

    subdag = DAG(
        '{}.{}'.format(dag.dag_id, task_id),
        schedule_interval=dag.schedule_interval,
        start_date=dag.start_date
    )

    # Replace the following 3 lines with code to automatically generate the desired tasks in the subdag
    t1 = DummyOperator(dag=subdag, task_id='t1')
    t2 = DummyOperator(dag=subdag, task_id='t2')
    t3 = DummyOperator(dag=subdag, task_id='t3')

    super(ExampleSubdagSubclassOperator, self).__init__(subdag=subdag, *args, **kwargs)

  # This property needs to be overridden so that the airflow UI recognises the task as a subdag and enables
  # the "Zoom into Sub Dag" button
  @property
  def task_type(self):
      return 'SubDagOperator'
```

Comment: Your trick is quite smart, but I'm skeptical as to why did they [mark it as a `TODO`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3617) until `Airflow 2.0`. There might be other considerations as well. Another thing that I'd like to change is to remove [this check](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py#L61) that enforces long `dag_id`s on `DAG`s used inside `SubDagOperator`s

Comment: In all python code, the above example is an instance of the SubDagOperator so the referenced code marked as "TODO remove in Airflow 2.0" will not be impacted. In fact, most things work without this trick as far as I can tell except the "Zoom into Subdag" button in the UI. The piece of code that enables this button is javascript and checks the task_type function.

Answer (score -1):

If you define the subdag as a dag itself this should work.

There is a good example from airflow. You also have to pay attention to the naming convention, the subdag name has to be of parent_name.child_name format.

the main dag

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_subdag_operator.py

the subdags
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/subdags/subdag.py

Comment: your answer doesn't address the problem asked in the question. **@subba** knew how to use `SubDagOperator` but was unable to extend it into a custom operator of his own