# Wiring top-level DAGs together

Tags: airflow

I need to have several identical (differing only in arguments) **top-level `DAG`s** that can also be triggered together with following constraints / assumptions:

- Individual top-level DAGs will have `schedule_interval=None` as they will only need occasional *manual triggering*
- The series of DAGs, however, needs to run daily
- *Order* and *number* of DAGs in series is fixed (known ahead of writing code) and changes rarely (once in a few months)
- Irrespective of whether a DAG fails or succeeds, the chain of triggering must not break
- Currently they must be run together in series; in future they may require parallel triggering

---

So I created one file for each DAG in my `dags` directory and now I must **wire them up for sequential execution**. I have identified two ways this could be done:

1. **`SubDagOperator`**

   - Works without a glitch in [my demo](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/subdag/dags/subdag_simplified.py)
   - Can [lead to *deadlocks*](https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/airflow-why-is-nothing-working-f705eb6b7b04) but there are [easy solutions](https://medium.com/@team_24989/fixing-subdagoperator-deadlock-in-airflow-6c64312ebb10); still there's a lot of [haze around using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301763)
   - SubDag's `dag_id` [must be prefixed](http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#subdags) by it's parent's, that would force *absurd* IDs on *top-level* DAGs that are supposed to be functional independently too
2. **`TriggerDagRunOperator`**

   - Works in [my demo](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/trigger-dag/dags/trigger_dag.py) but runs in *parallel* (not *sequentially*) as it doesn't *wait for triggered DAG* to finish before moving onto next one
   - `ExternalTaskSensor` might help overcome above limitation but it would make things very messy

---

My questions are

- How to overcome limitation of `parent_id` prefix in `dag_id` of `SubDag`s?
- How to force `TriggerDagRunOperator`s to **await completion of DAG**?
- Any alternate / better way to *wire-up* independent (top-level) DAGs together?
- Is there a workaround for my approach of *creating separate files* (for DAGs that differ only in input) for each top-level DAG?

---

I'm using [puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) with

- `Airflow 1.9.0-4`
- `Python 3.6-slim`
- `CeleryExecutor` with `redis:3.2.7`

---

**EDIT-1**

Clarifying **@Viraj Parekh**'s [queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328562/3679900)

> Can you give some more detail on what you mean by awaiting completion
>   of the DAG before getting triggered?

When I trigger the `import_parent_v1` DAG, all the 3 external DAGs that it is supposed to fire using `TriggerDagRunOperator` start running parallely even when I chain them sequentially. Actually the *logs* indicate that while they are fired one-after another, the execution moves onto next DAG (`TriggerDagRunOperator`) before the previous one has finished.
[image]
[image]
*NOTE: In this example, the top-level DAGs are named as `importer_child_v1_db_X` and their corresponding `task_id`s (for `TriggerDagRunOperator`) are named as `importer_v1_db_X`*

> Would it be possible to just have the TriggerDagRunOperator be the
>   last task in a DAG?

I have to chain several similar (differing only in arguments) DAGs together in a **workflow that triggers them one-by-one**. So there isn't just *one* `TriggerDagRunOperator` that I could put at last, there are many (here 3, but would be upto 15 in production)

Comment: As [reported by **@Freedom**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256675/airflow-how-to-extend-subdagoperator#comment85267925_42256675), `SubDagOperator` must not be extended until `Airflow v2.0`

Comment: Here are some links related in *some* way to this problem [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934266) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493605) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022323) [link4](https://medium.com/@hafizbadrie/airflow-when-your-dag-is-far-behind-the-schedule-ea11bf02e44c)

Comment: [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164160/airflow-dag-success-callback)

Comment: Here's the [link](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/a092fd4ff5bf58190310abdce58bbb50e95b615d572bb90cd88ecc45@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E) to my query on `Airflow` [`dev`-mailing-list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@airflow.apache.org)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking hints from **@Viraj Parekh**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328562/3679900), I was able to make `TriggerDagRunOperator` work in the intended fashion. I'm hereby posting my (partial) answer; will update as and when things become clear.

---

> How to overcome limitation of `parent_id` prefix in `dag_id` of `SubDag`s?

As told @Viraj, there's no straight way of achieving this. Extending `SubDagOperator` to remove [this check](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py#L61) might work but I decided to steer clear of it

---

> How to force `TriggerDagRunOperator`s to **await completion of DAG**?

- Looking at the [implementation](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/dagrun_operator.html#TriggerDagRunOperator), it becomes clear that the job of `TriggerDagRunOperator` is just to *trigger* external DAG; and that's about it. By default, it is not *supposed to* wait for completion of DAG. Therefore the behaviour I'm observing is understandable.
- `ExternalTaskSensor` is the obvious way out. However while learning basics of `Airflow` I was relying on *manual triggering* of DAGs (`schedule_interval=None`). In such case, `ExternalTaskSensor` makes it difficult to accurately specify `execution_date` for the external task (who's completion is being awaited), failing which the [sensor gets stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807297/).
- So taking hint from [implementation](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/sensors.html#ExternalTaskSensor), I made [minor adjustment](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/trigger-dag/dags/custom_task_sensor.py) to behaviour of `ExternalTaskSensor` by awaiting completion of *all `task_instance`s* of concerned task having

  `execution_date[external_task] >= execution_date[TriggerDagRunOperator] + execution_delta`

  This achieves the [desired result](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/trigger-dag/dags/trigger_dag_blocking.py): external DAGs run one-after-other in sequence.

---

> Is there a workaround for my approach of *creating separate files*
>   (for DAGs that differ only in input) for each top-level DAG?

Again going by @Viraj this can be done by [assigning DAGs to *global scope*](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/trigger-dag/dags/importer.py#L96) using `globals()[dag_id] = DAG(..)`

---

**EDIT-1**

Maybe I was referring to incorrect resource (the [link](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/sensors.html#ExternalTaskSensor) above is already dead), but [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.py) already includes the params `execution_delta` & `execution_date_fn` to easily restrict `execution_date`(s) for the task being *sensed*.

Comment: Although I haven't really used `ExternalTaskSensor` in any *real* `DAG`s, it still appears to be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54128117/3679900) to put to action

Comment: Also read about [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229812/3679900) that struck me and do care to report any *pitfalls* / reasons why it wouldn't work

Comment: Hi @y2k-shubham. in your final example, why did you choose 10 minutes in: `execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=10),`? How did you know 10 minutes?  why not 5 or 15?  Thanks.

Comment: *In such case, `ExternalTaskSensor` makes it difficult to accurately specify execution_date for the external task*: The `execution_date` field for `TriggerDagRunOperator()` is *templated*; use the same `execution_date` value as the parent DAG: `TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="...", trigger_dag_id="some_dag_id", execution_date="{{ts}}", ...)`, at which point the `ExternalTaskSensor()` will match exactly as it always uses the same `execution_date`, no delta required.

Comment: 2 years late. For your question on "How to force `TriggerDagRunOperator` to await completion of DAG?", there's a parameter called `wait_for_completion` that will only mark the Operator as `success` when the triggered DAG completes. Docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.2/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator).

Answer (score 2):

- Can you give some more detail on what you mean by awaiting completion of the DAG before getting triggered? Would it be possible to just have the TriggerDagRunOperator be the last task in a DAG?
- For creating DAGs similar DAGs, you can dynamically generate the DAGs from one Python file. You could do something like this:

from airflow import DAG

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               dag_number,
               default_args):

def hello_world_py(*args):
    print('Hello World')
    print('This is DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_number)))

dag = DAG(dag_id,
          schedule_interval=schedule,
          default_args=default_args)

with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='hello_world',
        python_callable=hello_world_py,
        dag_number=dag_number)

return dag


# build a dag for each number in range(10)
for n in range(1, 10):
dag_id = 'hello_world_{}'.format(str(n))

default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1)
                }

schedule = '@daily'

dag_number = n

globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id,
                              schedule,
                              dag_number,
                              default_args)
```

You can read more about that approach here. If most of you are producing DAGs are pretty similar, you might want to consider storing the config in an Airflow Variable[enter link description here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)

You probably won't be able to overcome the prefix limitations of the SubDag Operator - I'd suggest removing SubDags from your workflows entirely and just have them run as separate DAGs - it'll make it much easier to go back and re-run older DagRuns if you ever find yourself having to do that.

Comment: I don't understand the parameter `dag_number`. AFAIK, there's no such param in [`PythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.PythonOperator) or even [`BaseOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#baseoperator)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I was using schedule none.

```
trigger_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id=f'dag_id-trigger',
    trigger_dag_id='dag_id',
    python_callable=set_args,
    dag=dag,
)


def get_most_recent_dag_run(execution_date, **kwargs):
    return DagRun.find(dag_id='dag_id').pop().execution_date


sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id=f'dag_id-sensor',
    external_dag_id='dag_id',
    execution_date_fn=get_most_recent_dag_run,
    dag=dag,
    poke_interval=5,
    external_task_id='last_task_id' # This is task need to be in your external dag
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to wait for the triggered DAG completion, in Airflow 2.0 it became much easier than before.
There is a new version of the TriggerDagRunOperator allowing you to that. No need to use the ExternalTaskSensor anymore.
I've made a 10 mins tutorial about it https://youtu.be/8uKW0mPWmCk

Enjoy

Comment: FWIW (Not affiliated) Marc's videos are great! I watched them before stumbling here.  But for completeness of this answer,  you are looking for the new argument (added in Airflow 2.0)  `TriggerDagRunOperator(...,wait_for_completion=True, poke_interval=30)`