# Sensor won't be re-scheduled on worker failure

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm in the process of learning ins-and-outs of `Airflow` to end all our `Cron` woes. When trying to mimic failure of (`CeleryExecutor`) `worker`s, I've got stuck with `Sensor`s. I'm using `ExternalTaskSensor`s to **wire-up top-level `DAG`s together** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359972/3679900).

My current understanding is that since [`Sensor` is just a type of `Operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/sensors.html#BaseSensorOperator), it must inherit basic traits from [`BaseOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/models.html#BaseOperator). If I *kill* a `worker` (the `docker container`), all *ordinary* (*non-`Sensor`*) `task`s running on it get rescheduled on other `worker`s.

---

However upon killing a `worker`, `ExternalTaskSensor` does not get re-scheduled on a different `worker`; rather it gets stuck
[image: Stuck ExternalTaskSensor]

[image: Logs of ExternalTaskSensor after worker was killed]

Then either of following things happen:

- I just keep waiting for several minutes and then sometimes the `ExternalTaskSensor` is marked as failed but workflow resumes (it has happened a few times but I don't have a screenshot)
- I *stop* all `docker container`s (including those running `scheduler` / `celery` etc) and then restart them all, then the stuck `ExternalTaskSensor` gets rescheduled and *workflow* resumes. Sometimes it takes several stop-start cycles of `docker container`s to get the stuck `ExternalTaskSensor` resuming again

[image: stuck sensor]

*`Sensor` still stuck after single `docker container` stop-start cycle*

[image: stuck sensor resumes after docker container restart]

*`Sensor` resumes after several `docker container` stop-start cycles*

---

My questions are:

- Does `docker` have a role in this weird behaviour?
- Is there a difference between `Sensor`s (particularly `ExternalTaskSensor`) and other `operator`s in terms of *scheduling / retry behaviour*?
- How can I ensure that a `Sensor` is also rescheduled when the `worker` it is running on gets killed?

---

I'm using [puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/tree/6dc31a2cd849d5fce1b1942a12c29f4c0db69e93) with

- `Airflow 1.9.0-4`
- `Python 3.6-slim`
- `CeleryExecutor` with `redis:3.2.7`

This is the [link](https://github.com/y2k-shubham/docker-airflow/blob/trigger-dag/dags/trigger_dag_blocking.py) to my code.

Comment: All `operator`s in my *workflow* have `trigger_rule = 'all_done'`, so *workflow* is able to resume even after `ExternalTaskSensor` are marked *failed*