# Fusing operators together

Tags: airflow

I'm still in the process of deploying `Airflow` and I've already felt the need to *merge* `operator`s together. The most common use-case would be *coupling* an operator and the corresponding `sensor`. For instance, one might want to chain together the `EmrStepOperator` and `EmrStepSensor`.

---

I'm creating my `DAG`s [programmatically](https://www.data-essential.com/create-dynamic-workflow-in-apache-airflow/), and the biggest one of those contains 150+ (identical) *branches*, each performing the same series of operations on different bits of data (tables). Therefore **clubbing together tasks that make-up a single logical step** in my DAG would be of great help.

Here are 2 contending examples from my project to give motivation for my argument.

**1. Deleting data from S3 path and then writing new data**

This step comprises 2 operators

- `DeleteS3PathOperator`: Extends from `BaseOperator` & uses `S3Hook`
- `HadoopDistcpOperator`: Extends from `SSHOperator`

**2. Conditionally performing `MSCK REPAIR` on `Hive` table**

This step contains 4 operators

- `BranchPythonOperator`: Checks whether Hive table is *partitioned*
- `MsckRepairOperator`: Extends from `HiveOperator` and performs MSCK REPAIR on (*partioned*) table
- `Dummy(Branch)Operator`: Makes up *alternate branching path* to `MsckRepairOperator` (for non-partitioned tables)
- `Dummy(Join)Operator`: Makes up the *join step* for both branches

---

Using operators in *isolation* certainly offers smaller modules and more *fine-grained* logging / debugging, but in large DAGs, reducing the clutter might be desirable. From my current understanding there are 2 ways to chain operators together

1. `Hook`s

   Write actual *processing logic* in hooks and then use as many hooks as you want within a single operator (Certainly the better way in my opinion)
2. `SubDagOperator`

   A [risky](https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/airflow-why-is-nothing-working-f705eb6b7b04) and [controversial](https://medium.com/stanton-ventures-insights/airflow-lessons-from-the-data-engineering-front-in-chicago-9489e6ad5c3d) way of doing things; additionally the naming convention for SubDagOperator [makes me frown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900).

---

My questions are

- Should operators be *composed* at all or is it better to have *discrete* steps?
- Any pitfalls, improvements in above approaches?
- Any other ways to *combine* operators together?
- In *taxonomy* of Airflow, is the primary motive of Hooks same as above, or do they serve some other purposes too?

---

**UPDATE-1**

**3. Multiple Inhteritance**

While this is a `Python` feature rather than `Airflow` specific, its worthwhile to point out that *multiple inheritance* can come handy in combining functionalities of operators. [`QuboleCheckOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/qubole_check_operator.py), for instance, is already written using that. However in the past, I've tried this thing to fuse [`EmrCreateJobFlowOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_create_job_flow_operator.py) and [`EmrJobFlowSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/emr_job_flow_sensor.py), but at the time I had run into [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54529660/3679900) with [`@apply_defaults` decorator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/utils/decorators.py#L38) and had abandoned the idea.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/fdf1c956a655144db07745f6d79b2368b3e5ff4fd78363e7154128b2@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E) to my query to [Airflow users](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@airflow.apache.org) mailing list

Comment: In this context, I think we could explore these *hook-up methods* [`pre_execute(..)`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2694) and [`post_execute(..)`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2710). It appears that they are under-explored and I haven't found any concrete usage example even in `Airflow`'s codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have combined various hooks to create a Single operator based on my needs. A simple example is I clubbed gcs delete, copy, list method and get_size methods in hook to create a single operator called `GcsDataValidationOperator`. A rule of thumb would be to have **Idempotency** i.e. if you run multiple times it should produce the same result.

> Should operators be composed at all or is it better to have discrete
>   steps?

The only pitfall is maintainability, sometimes when the hooks change in the master branch, you will need to update all your operator manually if there are any breaking changes.

> Any pitfalls, improvements in above approaches?

You can use `PythonOperator` and use the in-built hooks with `.execute` method, but it would still mean a lot of details in the DAG file. Hence, I would still go for a new operator approach

> Any other ways to combine operators together?

Hooks are just interfaces to external platforms and databases like Hive, GCS, etc and form building blocks for operators. This allows the creation of new operators. Also, this mean you can customize templated field, add slack notification on each granular step inside your new operator and have your own logging details.

> In taxonomy of Airflow, is the primary motive of Hooks same as above, or do they serve some other purposes too?

FWIW: I am the PMC member and a contributor of the Airflow project.

Comment: Might I suggest that you abstract away the means of acquiring hooks and connections. That would (hopefully) make breaking changes easier to fix. Also let's you reuse code.

Comment: **@joeb** +1 turns out the community is headed in this very direction. (Yay!) For the uninformed, here is the [discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/7aaea178f8e3deeb1239726cb5a11fb1f504b45742946e8992866f57@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E) on recently opened [`AIP-14`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-14+Create+composable+operators+using+common+interfaces) titled `"Create composable operators using common interfaces"`

Answer (score 4):

This is not a generic answer to the question (although I think the approach is generic enough that it can be extended to other operators and sensors). It just shows how `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator` and `EmrJobFlowSensor` can be fused together using Python's multiple inheritance.

**Code for Fused Operator and Sensor**

```py
# Necessary imports

class EmrStartCluster(EmrCreateJobFlowOperator, EmrJobFlowSensor):
    ui_color = "#c70039"
    NON_TERMINAL_STATES = ["STARTING", "BOOTSTRAPPING"]

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["job_flow_id"] = None  # We do this, because EmrJobFlowSensor requires `job_flow_id` to be initialized
        super(EmrStartCluster, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.job_flow_id = super(EmrStartCluster, self).execute(context)
        super(EmrJobFlowSensor, self).execute(context)
        return self.job_flow_id
```

The fused operator can be invoked like:

```py
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {} ## Job flow config goes here
dag = DAG() # Dag invocation goes here

cluster_creator = EmrStartCluster(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='start_cluster',
    job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    emr_conn_id='emr_default'
)
```

I have tested it with `EmrStepSensor`, `EmrAddStepsOperator`, and `EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator` and so far have had no issues.