# How to combine Airflow operators?

Tags: airflow

Almost all of my DAGs will have a subset of repeating Operators. And because of my use case, it works out really well to create new wrapper Operators that combines multiple Operators in order to reduce boilerplate.

My question is how to go about combining them?

An example would be to query a database followed by sending a Slack message.

`postgres_operator_task >> slack_operator_task` -> `query_then_slack_operator_task`

Comment: There are probably many different ways to do this. You can define a custom operator which combines the different operators by executing the instructions in the right seqience, or define a subdag (which might be better if you are concerned about error recovery).

Comment: Refer to [Fusing operators together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53308306/3679900)

Answer (score 0):

Check the idea of subdags.
Resources:

- [SubDAGs - Ariflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=subdag#subdags) .
- [Using SubDAGs in Airflow -Astronomer](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/subdags/) .
- [Example subdag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/subdags/subdag.py) .

Comment: This is good. If I want to remove as much boilerplate as possible, I would like to wrap `SubDagOperator` + params into a custom operator. Is that an okay practice?

Comment: Sounds good for me, however I've heard 'SubDagOperator' can cause some troubles (and will be improved in v2). Friend gave me an idea that you can write just another 'Operator' which combines other operators (so it's almost what you wrote :) )