# ETL model with DAGs and Tasks

Tags: python, etl, airflow

I'm trying to model my ETL jobs with Airflow. All jobs have kind of the same structure:

1. Extract from a transactional database(N extractions, each one reading 1/N of the table)
2. Then transform data
3. Finally, insert the data into an analytic database

So `E >> T >> L`

This `Company Routine` USER >> PRODUCT >> ORDER has to run every 2 hours. Then I will have all the data from users and purchases.

How can I model it?

- The `Company Routine`(USER >> PRODUCT >> ORDER ) must be a DAG and each job must be a separate Task? In this case, how can I model each step(E, T, L) inside the task and make them behave like "sub-tasks" in Airflow?
- Or each job is a separate DAG? In this case. How can I say that I have to run The `Company Routine`(USER >> PRODUCT >> ORDER ) every 2h and they have these dependencies. Because as I could see, we can set cron time and dependencies only between tasks inside a DAG.

Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Now I'm using each `Company Routine`(USER >> PRODUCT >> ORDER ) as DAG and each job must be a separate Task.

Answer (score 0):

2nd option is better (have each *sub-workflow* of `Company Routine` as a top-level `DAG`) because

- top-level DAGs can be re-run independently (in case just one of them needs to be rerun) while you cannot rerun just *a part of a DAG* (if you modelled them as a monolithic DAG)
- same holds true for backfilling

---

But then you must link-up those top-level DAGs together too (so that they run one-after another). For that, see [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900)

Comment: Thank you, I will think more about this.