# How to define a DAG that scheduler a monthly job together with a daily job?

Tags: airflow

I have to

- update a table `Foo` monthly
- and another table `Bar` daily
- and join these two tables daily and insert the result into a third table `Bazz`

---

Is it possible to configure that

- `Foo` is updated on certain day (say 5th),
- while `Bar` is updated daily
- and they are in the same DAG?

Comment: Might be better to have them in separate dags, but you could have Foo check what day it is and if it isn't the 5th, it does nothing, while Bar and Bazz run.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour can be achieved within single DAG using either of following alternatives

- [ShortCircuitOperator](https://medium.com/@loraxman/how-and-why-of-airflow-shortciruitoperator-85dcbeddb1ba)
- [AirflowSkipException](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py) ([better](https://blog.diffractive.io/2018/08/07/replacement-shortcircuitoperator-for-airflow/) in my opinion)

Basically, your DAG would still run each day (`schedule_interval='@daily'`), but

- on a daily basis, only your `Bar` task would run while `Foo` would get skipped (or *short-circuited*);
- until on some particular day (like 5th of each month) when both would run.

---

You can, of course, also model these as separate DAGs and [chain them together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900) (rather than individual tasks within a single DAG). This choice [might be better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081651/3679900) as long as the number of DAGs that you are linking together is small.

---

Related: [Schedule airflow job bi-weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63565229/3679900)