# Execute the task on Airflow on 12th day of the month and 2 days before the last day of the month

Tags: airflow

I need to execute the airflow same task on 12th day of the month and 2 days before the last day of the month.

I was trying with macros and `execution_date` as well. Not sure how to proceed further. Could you please help on this?

```
def check_trigger(execution_date, day_offset, **kwargs):
    target_date = execution_date - timedelta(days = day_offset)
    return target_date
```

Comment: For scheduling criteria that cannot be realised via `crontab` expressions, you can always rely on *programming-logic*: [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108259/3679900) task(s) when you don't want to run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it like below. And `twelfth_or_two_before` is a Python function that simply checks the date & returns the `task_id` of the appropriate downstream task. (That way if the business needs ever change & you need to run the actual tasks on a different/additional day(s), you just modify that function.)

```
with DAG( ... ) as dag:
    right_days = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="start",
        python_callable="twelfth_or_two_before,
    )
    do_nothing = DummyOperator(task_id="do_nothing")
    actual_task = ____Operator( ... )  # This is the Operator that does actual work
    start >> [do_nothing, actual_task]
```