# How to combine multiple DAGs in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I really need to know how to use Airflow to have multiple DAGs call each other (e.g. `DAG_1 >> DAG_2`) similar to how it uses the upstream/downstream operators to run tasks within a DAG.  I need to know how to set this up so Airflow will run `DAG_1`, then will run `DAG_2` once `DAG_1` has completed successfully.

Preferably I would like to have `DAG_1` and `DAG_2` in separate files within the Airflow **dag** folder, then either have `DAG_2` call `DAG_1` as a pre-step at the start of its run, or have a separate "main" DAG which creates and runs a DAG where each task is another DAG rather than a task operator.

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know, I really need some help here.  I will also accept making and connecting two separate DAGs in the same file if anyone knows how to do that, but preferably the linked DAGs will be in different files.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325525/wiring-top-level-dags-together)

Comment: @mattc-7 kindly accept the answer if it solved your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py) which takes the DAG id as a parameter and triggers it

see official example [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py)