# Airflow: Master Dag with ExternalTaskSensor gets stuck forever

Tags: airflow

The requirement is to have DAG run one after the other and on success of each DAG

I have a Master DAG in which I am calling all the DAG to get executed one after the other in sequence

Also in each of the dag_A, dag_B, dag_C I have to given schedule_interval = None and manually turn ON in GUI

I am using ExternalTaskSensor, coz even before all the tasks in the first dag_A gets completed, it kicks off the second dag_B, to avoid such issues I am using ExternalTaskSensor.If any better implementation please kindly let me know

Don't know What I am missing here

**Code: master_dag.py**

```
import datetime
import os
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.models import DAG, Variable

from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 7),
        'provide_context': True,
        'execution_timeout': None,
        'retries': 0,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3),
        'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
    }


dag = DAG(
        dag_id='master_dag',
        schedule_interval='7 3 * * *',
        default_args=default_args,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False,
    )

trigger_dag_A = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_dag_A',
        trigger_dag_id='dag_A',
        dag=dag,
    )

wait_for_dag_A = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dag_A',
    external_dag_id='dag_A',
    external_task_id='proc_success',
    poke_interval=60,
    allowed_states=['success'],
    dag=dag,
    )

trigger_dag_B = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag_B',
        trigger_dag_id='dag_B',
        dag=dag,
    )

wait_for_dag_B = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dag_B',
    external_dag_id='dag_B',
    external_task_id='proc_success',
    poke_interval=60,
    allowed_states=['success'],
    dag=dag)

trigger_dag_C = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag_C',
        trigger_dag_id='dag_C',
        dag=dag,
    )

trigger_dag_A >> wait_dag_A >> trigger_dag_B >> wait_dag_B >> trigger_dag_C
```

Each of the DAG has multiple tasks running with last task been proc_success

Answer (score 2):

Background

- [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.py) works by polling the state of `DagRun` / `TaskInstance` of the external `DAG` or `task` respectively (based on whether or not `external_task_id` is passed)
- Now since a single `DAG` can have multiple active `DagRun`s, the sensor must  be told that which of these runs / instances it is supposed to *sense*
- For that, it uses `execution_date` as a distinguishing criteria. This can be expressed in (only) **one of** following two ways

> ```
> :param execution_delta: time difference with the previous execution to
>     look at, the default is the same execution_date as the current task or DAG.
>     For yesterday, use [positive!] datetime.timedelta(days=1). Either
>     execution_delta or execution_date_fn can be passed to
>     ExternalTaskSensor, but not both.
> :type execution_delta: datetime.timedelta
> ```

> ```
> :param execution_date_fn: function that receives the current execution date
>     and returns the desired execution dates to query. Either execution_delta
>     or execution_date_fn can be passed to ExternalTaskSensor, but not both.
> :type execution_date_fn: callable
> ```

---

The problem in your implementation

- In your `ExternalTaskSensor`s, you are not passing either of `execution_date_fn` or `execution_delta` params
- as a result, the sensor [picks up its own `execution_date`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.py#L104) to poll for `DagRun`s of *child* `DAG`s, thereby getting stuck (clearly the `execution_date` of your parent / orchestrator DAG would be different from child DAGs)

> ```
> @provide_session
> def poke(self, context, session=None):
>     if self.execution_delta:
>         dttm = context['execution_date'] - self.execution_delta
>     elif self.execution_date_fn:
>         dttm = self.execution_date_fn(context['execution_date'])
>     else:
>         # if neither of above is passed, use current DAG's execution date
>         dttm = context['execution_date']
> ```

---

Further tips

- You can skip passing `external_task_id`; when you do that, the `ExternalTaskSensor`, in effect, becomes an *`ExternalDagSensor`*. This is particularly helpful when your child DAGs (A, B & C) have more than one *end task* (so that completion of any one of those end-tasks doesn't guarantee the completion of entire DAG)
- Also have a look at this discussion: [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900)

---

---

**EDIT-1**

On an afterthought, my initial judgement appears to be wrong; particularly following statement doesn't hold true.

> clearly the execution_date of your parent / orchestrator DAG would be
> different from child DAGs

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L74), it becomes clear the `TriggerDagRunOperator` passes its own `execution_date` to child `DagRun`, meaning that the `ExternalTaskSensor` should then be able to *sense* that DAG or it's task.

```
 trigger_dag(
            dag_id=self.trigger_dag_id,
            run_id=run_id,
            conf=self.conf,
            # own execution date passed to child DAG
            execution_date=self.execution_date,
            replace_microseconds=False,
        )
```

so then the explanation holds no truth.

I would suggest you to

- check the `execution_date` of your triggered child DAGs / the tasks whose `external_task_id` you are passing, in the UI or by querying meta-db
- and compare it with `execution_date` of your orchestrator DAG

that should clarify certain bits

Comment: Thanks for a details explanation, appreciate your response

Comment: **@Kar** if you were able to solve the problem, please consider adding the solution as an answer here for reference to others.